# A strange issue about Input[type=email] and Chinese

Tags: javascript

Here's an `input[type=email]`

[image]

The question is, when I type in Chinese **after the "@"**, then it strangely becomes garbled when submiting. Like this:

[image]

I know Chinese text will get decoded when submiting, but the correct form is:

[image]

Obviously different.

If I change the `[type=email]` to `[type=text]`, it will become all right.

So what's wrong with the `[type=email]`?

Comment: I mean that Chinese text normally are not allowed in an email text and it won't get through the validation. But when the Chinese character occurs after the "@", it is validated. This is the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The browser is following [the specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/forms.html#e-mail-state-(type=email):concept-fe-value-6), which says user agents should convert the displayed value to/from [Punycode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punycode) within `input[type="email"]` elements:

> User agents may transform the value for display and editing; in particular, user agents should convert punycode in the domain labels of the value to IDN in the display and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

You can try defining language in the input

```
 <input type="email" lang="zh">
```

### Codes

Chinese     zh

Chinese (Simplified)    zh-Hans

Chinese (Traditional)   zh-Hant